# Strange (for me) error in Python OOP

Tags: python, oop

I'm a newbie and I'm having a really strange (like in the title, for me) problem.
This is the code:

```
    from random import shuffle
    class Carta:
            listaSemi=[" ","Bastoni","Spade","Coppe","Denari"]
            listaValori=[" ","Asso","Due","Tre","Quattro",
    "Cinque","Sei","Sette","Otto","Nove","Dieci"]   
            def __init__(self,seme,valore):
                    self.seme=seme
                    self.valore=valore
            def __str__(self):
                    s1=self.listaValori[self.valore]
                    s2=self.listaSemi[self.seme]        
                    return " ".join((s1,"di",s2))
    class Mazzo:
            def __init__(self):
                    self.Carte=[]
            def Crea(self):
                    for seme in range(1,5):
                            for valore in range(1,11):
                                    self.Carte.append(Carta(seme, valore))
            def Mescola(self):
                    shuffle(self.Carte)
```

When i do:

```
M=Mazzo
Mazzo.Crea(M)
```

I get:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#62>", line 1, in <module>
    Mazzo.Crea(M)
  File "/home/administrator/Scrivania/Script/Carte.py", line 19, in Crea
    self.Carte.append(Carta(seme, valore))
  AttributeError: type object 'Mazzo' has no attribute 'Carte'
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you want `M` to be an instance of `Mazzo`?  Then do `M=Mazzo()` with parenthesis.  Otherwise `M` is just a reference to the class `Mazzo` and  `Mazzo.Crea(M)` just means `Mazzo.Crea(Mazzo)`.  Once `M` is an instance of `Mazzo`, `Mazzo.Crea(M)` can also be written `M.Crea()`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `M.Crea()` and `M = Mazzo()` ? Also your `Crea()` method takes no parameter, so `Mazzo.Crea(M)` is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your time, guys. I'm really sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Nobody was born knowing python, we all struggled to acquire the knowledge we have.  No need to apologize!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initilizing your class incorrectly. Try doing this:

```
m = Mazzo()
m.Crea()
```

So a quick explanation as to why. First of all, the first line initializes an object of type `Mazzo` and sets in to m (please note the '()' you need that for all methods, initialization or otherwise.) Since its only perimeter is `self` it can be left blank.

Next we want to call the Crea function, we do this by calling the object we just created and NOT the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning type to M instead of creating a new object. Probably you want to do this:

```
m=Mazzo()
m.Crea()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in how you are instantiating the class **Mazzo**

```
>>>M=Mazo
```

What is really assigned to **M** is the class object and not a Mazzo object:

```
>>>type(M)
<class 'type'>
```

Your next line is even more problematic:

```
>>> Mazzo.Crea(M)
```

That asks the Mazzo class to execute the Crea method, with a Mazzo class object as the argument.  And Crea doesn't take any other arguments, let alone a class object.  I suspect you may have some more reading to do about the **self** method argument in python.

The usual way of instantiating a new object of a given class is something like:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
        def __init__(self,someValue):
            self.someValue = someValue
        def aMethod(self)
            print(self.someValue)

>>> newObject = MyClass(42)
>>> newObject.aMethod()
42
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you did

`M=Mazzo
Mazzo.Crea(M)`

What you did is `Mazzo.Crea(Mazzo)`.

First off, `M=Mazzo` should be `M=Mazzo()`. When you call just plain `Mazzo`, it doesn't trigger `__init__`, although `Mazzo()` does.

FYI: calling Mazzo.Crea(Mazzo) will raise a TypeError, as in

`TypeError: Crea takes exactly 1 argument (2 Given)`